# Frobenius condition in terms of Lie brackets

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

Let $\alpha$ be a $1$-form and $\xi = \ker \alpha$.

Frobenius theorem tells us that $\xi$ is integrable iff $\alpha\wedge{\rm d}\alpha = 0
.$

In the book "Introduction to Contact Topology" from Hansjorg Geiges, he claims (page $3$) that in terms of Lie bracket this is equivalent to $[X,Y] \in \xi$ $\forall ~X,Y \in \xi$, where $X \in \xi$ means that $X$ is a smooth vector field and $X_p \in \xi_p\ \forall p \in M$

I don't understand why that claim is true. A proof of this fact would be most welcomed.

Thank in advance.

Comment: Just as an aside: a distribution satisfying the Lie bracket condition you wrote is called involutive. (Frobenius theorem is: completely integrable iff integrable iff involutive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use that $${\rm d}\alpha(X,Y) = X(\alpha(Y)) - Y(\alpha(X)) -\alpha([X,Y]). \qquad (\ast)$$

Suppose that $\alpha \wedge{\rm d}\alpha = 0$ and let's check that $\xi$ is closed by the Lie bracket. Let $X,Y \in \xi$. Then $(\ast)$ becomes ${\rm d}\alpha(X,Y) = -\alpha([X,Y])$. Evaluating $\alpha \wedge {\rm d}\alpha$ at the triple $([X,Y],X,Y)$ and using again that $Y\in \xi$ gives $$0 = -\alpha([X,Y])^2,$$whence $[X,Y] \in \xi$.

Now suppose that $\xi$ is closed by the Lie bracket and let's check that $\alpha\wedge {\rm d}\alpha = 0$. Take $p \in M$. If $\alpha_p = 0$, done. Otherwise take a local frame $X_1,\cdots,X_n$ around $p$ with the $n-1$ first ones in $\xi$. It suffices to check that $\alpha \wedge {\rm d}\alpha $ evaluated at $(X_i,X_j,X_k)$ is zero. If the index $n$ repeats, done. If the index $n$ does not appear, done. If the index $n$ appears once, we can suppose that $k = n$ and $i,j < n$. Then $$(\alpha \wedge {\rm d}\alpha)(X_i,X_j,X_n) = \alpha(X_i){\rm d}\alpha(X_j,X_n) - \alpha(X_n) {\rm d}\alpha(X_i,X_j) = 0,$$since $\alpha(X_i) = 0$ because $X_i \in \xi$ and ${\rm d}\alpha(X_i,X_j) = 0$, since $X_i,X_j \in \xi$, $\xi$ is closed under Lie bracket, and we use $(\ast)$ again.

Comment: Thank you ! That was realy helpful.

just a quesion : under what conditions (*) holds ? Is it true for Any 1-form and vector fields X, Y ?

Comment: @Thalanza Equation $(\ast)$ holds for any $1-$ form and any vector fields $X$ and $Y$ - it can be used as the definition of ${\rm d}\alpha$; see for example page $356$ in *The Geometry of Kerr Black Holes*, by O'Neill.

Comment: And by the way, notice that we've proven the lemma in the end of said page :)