# About codifying length and energy using a one-form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds, semi-riemannian-geometry

Let $M^n$ be a smooth manifold and $g$ be a Riemannian metric on $M$.

> Is there $\omega \in \Omega^1(M)$ such that $\int_c \omega = \ell(c)$ for every curve in $M$?

In general the answer seems to be no. In Spivak's *A Comprehensive Introduction to Differential Geometry (volume $1$)* he gives this argument for $\Bbb R^2$ with the usual metric: if $\omega$ is such a non-zero form, then $\ker \omega$ is a one dimensional distribution in $\Bbb R^2$ - and every curve contained in a integral submanifold of $\ker \omega$ will have length zero.

If in the general case we consider $\omega$ a non-zero form, then $\ker \omega$ will be a $(n-1)-$dimensional distribution in $M$, which, by Frobenius' theorem, will be integrable if and only if $\omega \wedge {\rm d}\omega = 0$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1832179/frobenius-condition-in-terms-of-lie-brackets/1832280#1832280)). If such condition holds we proceed like in the $\Bbb R^2$ case (in which the condition holds trivially).

But I see no reason for that condition to necessarily hold. Is there an example of manifold with a one-form like this?

This also leads me to wonder (from here on it's mostly food for thought and I'll be happy with the previous question answered):

- what if $g$ is pseudo-Riemannian? The possibility of lightlike curves in the integral submanifold seems to make the reasoning above fail.
- what if we looked at energy instead of length? The situation seems the same, but energy depends on the parametrization, which ends up depending on a coordinate system (ok, maybe that second question is not so interesting after all)

Comment: I think in the $n$-dimensional case you can still use Spivak's argument by taking a horizontal curve (even though there are not full $n-1$ dimensional integral submanifolds there are still 1-dimensional curves tangent to the distribution).

Comment: This is why complex geometry, in particular, Kähler manifolds, is such a wonderful world. There you have a global $(k,k)$ form on a complex $n$-manifold whose restriction to *any* complex $k$-dimensional submanifold is the volume form. ... By the way, your query can't even work for a $1$-dimensional Riemannian manifold (take a curve that goes back and forth a few times!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x\in M$, let $\gamma : [0, t] \to M$ be $\gamma(s) = \exp_x (sX)$ for some $X \in T_xM$, with $\|X\|  =1$. Then $\ell (\gamma) = t$. Thus

$$ \int_0^t \omega_{ \gamma(s)} (\gamma'(s)) ds = t$$

for all $t$. Differentiating gives

$$1 = \omega_{\gamma(t)} (\gamma'(t))$$

for all $t$. Putting $t=0$ gives $1 = \omega_x (X)$. But $X \in T_pM$ is arbitrary and this is nonsense.